# Is it possible to set the MaxWidth of a control using VisualStateManager

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, visualstatemanager

Is it possible to set the maxwidth of a control using VisualStateManager in xaml?
I get following exception in blend when i try to set the maxwidth of a control:

ArgumentException: Invalid attribute value  for property MaxWidth.

xaml is

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxWidth)" Storyboard.TargetName="AbcControl" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
```

Comment: Did you somewhere set a start value for the animation, either by setting `AbcControl.MaxWidth` before starting the animation, or by setting the animation's `From` property?

Comment: no, i did not. it would be really helpful if you can drop a line of xaml describing this.

Comment: @Clemens got some clue from you reply.. following lines made it work.. although i had to write those line manually instead of blend generating them automatically                                                           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AbcControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxWidth)">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1000" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

Comment: @MakeItPerfect, please add your solution into an answer and tick it as the correct answer when you can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following xaml made it work.. although i had to write those line manually instead of blend generating them automatically

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="AbcControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxWidth)"> <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1000" /> </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```